# How can I do an automated export of a Azure SQL Database in the new portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I am using the new Azure Portal and have selected the Azure SQL Database.

With the old portal I was able to set up an automated daily export of the database but with the new one I absolutely cannot find out how to do this. It really seems like it is not possible.

Does anyone know how if there is a place where I can set up automated .bacpac exports in the new portal?

Comment: The automated daily export of the database in the old portal is using Azure Automation?

Comment: I found the automated export on the database config tab.  But can't find anything like that in the new portal.

Comment: What is your scenario?

Comment: azure already provides point in time restore for your db.  see : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-user-error-recovery/
unless you need to get copies for on premises testing etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automated Database export is not currently a feature of the new Microsoft Azure Portal.  A few options for mitigations: 1) For Basic, Standard, and Premium databases, automatic backups of the databases are taken for durations of 7, 21, and 35 days respectively 2) manual export is still an option 3) automatic export via the old portal.

Comment: How do I access the old portal?

Comment: Old portal will work only until march 2017 and there's no equivalent feature in new portal as of now

Comment: New portal has option to export database `.bacpac` to storage account.

Comment: @stom yes, but the emphasis is on automated. that's not available anymore it seems